# Case sensitive string comparison in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I know there is a collation in MSSQL that can be used for case sensitive comparison - `Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS`.

I have checked in ClickHouse documentation and else where, but couldn't find if there is a collation that can be used for case sensitive joins or String comparisons in ClickHouse. If it's really possible in ClickHouse, could you guide me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a collation for case-sensitive comparisons, because [Functions for Searching in Strings](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions):

> All functions in this section search by default case-sensitively. Case-insensitive search is usually provided by separate function variants. Note that case-insensitive search follows the lowercase-uppercase rules of the English language.

Comparison, which checks if two strings are exactly the same, including their case. You can do this by using the `=` operator to compare strings directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM stackoverflow
WHERE name = 'manoman'
```

Comparisons are case-sensitive unless you explicitly specify a case-insensitive comparison using a function like `lower()` [lower](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-functions#lower):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM stackoverflow
WHERE lower(name) = 'manoman'
```

Comment: I need the case sensitive comparison because I need to identify the case sensitive mismatches. I will  heck if the default is case sensitive. Thanks.

Comment: Note that collation still applies if ordering, in which cases its case insensitive if you specify. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/order-by#collation-support
LIKE AND ILIKE also supported.